# Is there another API like UIPopOverController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller

I want to make a pop view as the pic shows below (in the red box):
[image]

I find the UIPopOverController can make the pop view, but it looks like a table (scroll vertically). It doesn`t look like the right-left section style as the pic shows above. I am wondering if this is another IOS API？ Or it is totally custom made?

Show me any clue , thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The menu you are referring to is controlled by the [UIMenuController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/UIMenuController.html).

Customise the menu items like:

```
UIMenuItem *menuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Do Something"
                                                  action:@selector(aSelector:)];
[[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuItems: @[menuItem]];
```

You will have to implement `canPerformAction:withSender:` in a custom view class.

[NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/uimenucontroller/) has a nice article.